# Why sprite picture doesn't change immedietely?

Tags: css

I want the picture to "blink", i.e. to get changed immedietely, but it works like a carousel. Where have I made a mistake?

Here is the code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/1o63nrrv3t

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  height: 850px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 400px;
  top: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOemp.png") center top no-repeat;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  animation: play 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: center -75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Logo</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: SO prefers you to past your code in here to benefit the community. If your link disapears then the page becomes useless for anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this css instead to make it work

```
    body {
    background-color: black;
    }

    .logo {
      height: 850px;
      width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .logo:before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 75px;
      width: 400px;
      top: 400px;
      z-index: 1;
      background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOemp.png") center top no-repeat;
      font-size: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      animation: play 1s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes play {
      0%{
        background-position:center top;
      }
      50%{
        background-position:center top;
      }
      51%{
        background-position:center bottom;
      }

      100% {
        background-position:center bottom;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your picture to blink all you have to do is use the opacity

```
body {
background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  height: 850px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 400px;
  top: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOemp.png") center top no-repeat;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  animation: play 1s infinite;
  opacity:0;
}
@keyframes play {
  from{opacity:0;}
  to {opacity:1;}
}
```

[see your example here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/feg9rmgi)